# ATI Catalyst didn't update correctly and now can't boot

Tags: software-installation, 11.04, amd-graphics

I recently bought a barebones PC with Ubuntu 11.04 64-bit installed and it worked correctly, but the video wasn't great. So I tried downloading ATI Catalyst from ATI web and tried to install.

Ubuntu asked me to first uninstall the old Catalyst or force the installation. I tried forcing, and then after rebooting, the system froze and showed a failure saying automatic crash report generation.

Next, I tried rebooting in safe mode, which worked correctly, then I tried to reinstall ATI, but it showed an error at installation.

Rebooting the system, it now shows a black screen and does nothing. I can't currently use my PC, can someone help to fix this?

Comment: What error message ?

Comment: I had the same problem. I ended up reinstalling Ubuntu and just using the ATI driver from the restricted drivers manager, didn't bother updating it. At the moment I'm using Gnome-Classic, I would like to have the driver updated in order to use Gnome-Shell, though.

Comment: I Had the same problem, ended up re-installing. Sorry. :(

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the only "solution" that I've seen when I had to do this (and the comments above back me up) is to re-install Ubuntu ***without*** wiping the harddrive.

Answer (score 0):

For those drivers problem i'm using some from [Oibaf's PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eoibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers)
till now works fine.